# How to create tests with data input in perl

Tags: perl, testing

I have started writing a module I can use to summarize data. I am new to testing, and while I've read what I could find and googled around I could not find advice on how to best test methods and subs that require some input data to make sense (let's say I'd use about 100 lines of tab separated text file).

Should I just include the text file in the distribution? I've checked Text::CSV and that's the way it's done there.

Any advice?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a combination of using [Test::More](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) as your testing framework and embedding inline data.

`Test::More` is the standard testing toolkit in Perl; just about every testing tool you might find uses it. It comes with lots of handy built-in testing features.

Generally, you do your testing by comparing an expected value against what the subroutine or tool actually gave.  The most common way to do that is with a straight comparison, using the `is` routine.  It's format looks like this:

```
is($got, $expected, $test_name);
```

For example, lets say we made a POW function, and wanted to make sure it's working:

```
sub pow { my ($n, $p) = @_;  return $n ** $p; }
```

We would check this with:

```
is( pow(2, 3), 8, "2^3 is 8" );
is( pow(2, 4), 16, "2^4 is 16" );
is( pow(3, 3), 27, "3^3 is 27" );
```

Then it just comes down to getting the data you need in a format that's useful to you.  Small data might be loaded inline with your test function calls using Heredocs :

```
my $test1 = <<'END_DATA1';
... (your data here
END_DATA1

my $test2 = <<'END_DATA2';
... (your second dataset here
END_DATA2
```

Alternatively, if you one big data set you need to check multiple parts of, you may consider putting it all in the `__DATA__` block:

```
while (my $line = <DATA>) { ... } # read from the DATA handle

# ... your script above here; everything below __DATA__ is read from the handle
__DATA__  
... ( your data set here )
```

So for example, if you want to make sure your subroutine reads in a line correctly, it might be something like:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

use Your::Lib;  # load your library with your routines in it

use Test::More tests => 5; # how many checks you will perform, in case it dies

my $lib = your_lib_function(\*DATA);  # say, it loads from a file handle maybe?

is( $lib->key1(), 'value', "Key 1 was read correctly.");
is( $lib->key2(), 'value2', "Key 2 was read correctly.");
is( $lib->key3(), 'value3', "Key 3 was read correctly.");
is( $lib->key4(), 'value4', "Key 4 was read correctly.");
is( $lib->key5(), 'value5', "Key 5 was read correctly.");

__DATA__
{
    "Key" : "value",
    "Key2" : "value2",
    "Key3" : "value3",
    "Key4" : "value4",
    "Key5" : "value5",
}
```

Check out the [`Test::More`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Test%3a%3aMore) for even more details about how this framework works.  Good luck! :)